# ¿Cómo instalar un apk desde otra apk ya instalada?

Tags: android, android-studio

Deseo realizar una app instalador de apks

El asunto se trata de que al hacer click en un boton se mande llamar un archivo apk ubicado en el mismo celular para realizar una instalación del mismo, he encontrado algunas preguntas parecidas pero no son lo que busco, por ejemplo esto:

```
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app.smeter");
         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);                 
         startActivity(intent); 

        }
    });
```

Esto abriria un apk ya instalada en el dispositivo, en mi caso no está instalada entonces quisiera saber si hay alguna forma con intent de hacer que se abra dicho archivo y si es posible al terminar de instalar se desinstale el instalador

Comment: Ese tipo de aplicaciones si las aprueba Google?

Comment: es un proyecto escolar, no está pensado en buscar la aprobación de google

Comment: @Bicho no las aprueba y de hecho poder instalarla propiamente no se puede, lo único que puede realizar es abrir un .apk.

Answer (score 0):

**Por seguridad no es posible forzar la instalación de una aplicación desde otra aplicación.**

Lo único que puedes realizar es abrir el APK de la aplicación que deseas instalar, pero este APK debe ser previamente descargado, para abrirlo puedes usar un `Intent`:

```
//Obtiene ubicación de APK.
String filePath = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/Downloads/myApp.apk";
//Realiza intent para abrir .apk
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```